# jQuery remove last three elements after specific element

Tags: jquery

How do I remove the **last three** items (which have the same class), after a specific element (p#heading)?

```
<p id="heading">HEADING</p>
<p class="txt"></p>
<p class="txt"></p>
<p class="txt"></p>
<p class="txt"></p>
<p class="txt"></p>
<p class="txt"></p>
```

Thanks already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches `.txt` elements [after](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) `p#heading` and [slices](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) the selection to the last three in the matched set.

```
$matchedElements = $('p#heading').nextAll('.txt').slice(-3);​​
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("p#heading").siblings(".txt").slice(-3).remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work, because the p.txt elements are NOT inside p#heading. Fixed the heading typo, to make it more clear. Sorry. :)

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot! Josh Davenport's .nextAll() does the job too!

Comment: @fishbaitfood: FYI, if there are `.txt` elements before `p#heading` they will be matched too. See [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) docs. It won't match elements _after_ as you asked

Comment: Hmmm.. It did work however. I'll go with your .nextAll() then, to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `~` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allTxt = $('#heading ~ .txt');
    var toBeRemoved = allTxt.slice(allTxt.length - 3);
    toBeRemoved.remove();
});​​
```

Comment: Didn't even know about that selector!